# Domino server crashes on startup

Tags: linux, lotus-domino

OS is SLES 11 SP4; 
Domino 8.5.1FP5

On trying to start the server it crashes immediately with:

Fatal Error signal = 0x0000000b PID/TID = 6944/-184699184

This happens since I installed patches of SLES11. I can't tell which patches exactly, because I just accepted what was offered as security patches.
The crash happens independent of other user applications. I.e. I tried runlevel 2 also. And I run the Fixpack5 twice again. Id est reverting by this the fixpack and installing it again. No change of behaviour! The file created by nsd contains huge information, but I can't see anything evident to me to find the cause!
A hint may be:

INFO: (/opt/ibm/lotus/notes/latest/linux/memcheck)  4 errors, 0 warnings

Generated Memcheck Messages:

ERROR (50): couldn't get shared memory key '0xf8df8000' stats - (14) Bad address

ERROR (48): couldn't access shared memory key '0xf8df8000' - (14) Bad address

ERROR (50): couldn't get shared memory key '0xf8df8001' stats - (14) Bad address

ERROR (48): couldn't access shared memory key '0xf8df8001' - (14) Bad address

but I couldn't determine any memory error with other applications, and trying to do manual memchecks tells nothing different.

I have some warnings like:

Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=39c1043d2fcf5b72a2199cfb765d020b1faeb863"

I tried all of them, but get only the message: nothing to do!

Any body out here with experience of the case?

Comment: Ask this over at Server Fault... this is not about programming...

Comment: Oh! Didn't know about server fault. Thanks for the hint.